# pip install: How to force a specific package version

Tags: django, pip

I'm trying to install Django 1.4.3, but when I execute pip install, pip keeps installing Django 1.5 version instead 1.4.3

`sudo pip install -I Django==1.4.3`

It returns:

```
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.3
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django
    
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
=== >>>> Requested Django==1.4.3, but installing version 1.5 <<<< ====
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.5
    Uninstalling Django:
      Successfully uninstalled Django
  Running setup.py install for Django
    
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...
```

but if I execute pip freeze, it keeps showing

Django==1.5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried uninstalling all versions of Django, and then running your command?

Comment: yes I did and doesn't work. I also have the alternative to download the package and install it manually, but I want to know if there's an option in pip to avoid this behaviour and force the 1.4.3 version

Comment: have you tried only `pip install Django==1.4.3`

Comment: yes I did and the result was the same

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This could/should/can be helped by clearing the build dir for Django in pip.
There is a bug for this, since version 1.1 [see here for details](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/709)

You can start checking for these folders here if you're on OS X or unix like systems:

```
~/.pip 
/tmp/pip-build-root (or pip-build-$USER, if you aren't running pip as root).
```

This is if you haven't specified a new build folder when you installed the first version of Django.

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't work, neither with -v flag nor setting "Django<=1.5" or using 'Django==1.4.3'. It outputs no error, the 1.5 version installs correctly but keeps saying Requested Django==1.4.3, but installing version 1.5.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the -V flag is only for outputting the version of pip currently installed and has nothing to do with `pip install`.

Comment: @aiham you are 100% correct, just woke up and was planning on fixing the answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I'm currently trying to go back from 1.5.1 to 1.5.0 but pip 1.3.1 refuses to do it. I've ensured all django versions have been uninstalled, and there is no build directory in my current directory (is it supposed to be somewhere else?). This is what I've used: `sudo pip install -I 'django==1.5.0'` but I still get: "Requested django==1.5.0, but installing version 1.5.1". Any other ideas?

Comment: Using 1.5 instead of 1.5.0 has the same result. I figured maybe 1.5.0 doesn't even exist, so I tried 1.4.5 (because I'm certain it exists) yet it still installs 1.5.1.

Comment: check ~/.pip and ~/tmp/ folders if you're on os x.

Comment: I'm on OS X but it wasn't there. I found it in /tmp/pip-build-root/. I shall clear it and try again, thanks.

Comment: It worked. I should've noticed it earlier but pip wasn't downloading anything new until I cleared that folder. Thank you. Btw, it would be useful for others if update your answer with the possible locations of the build folder.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu and found the build directory in the same location, /tmp/pip-build-root. There is also a /tmp/pip-build-<username> directory you may need to remove if you ran into issues doing a non-sudo pip install.

Answer (score 8):

As [limelight says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691041/383793), you should empty your cache and build directories, or pass in a temporary clean location with the `--download-cache` and  flag.

```
$ pip help install
[...]
--download-cache <dir>      Cache downloaded packages in <dir>.
-b, --build <dir>           Directory to unpack packages into and build in. The default in a virtualenv is "<venv path>/build". The default for global installs is
                          "<OS temp dir>/pip-build-<username>".
```

I'd like to warn any readers to not use `sudo pip install` to install Django. It installs Django system-wide. And changing the system-wide version could break system-packages that depend on it. For instance, Ubuntu MAAS and Cobbler depend on the system django package. These are typically services you don't want to break.

If you need a different version than the system-package, use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to isolate your dependencies from the system.

OP seems to be on OSX and I don't know of any server-wide Mac Django, but that may change. Consider installing python packages with `sudo` at par to changing the system-installed python with python 3; it might work for now, but have some paracetamol in stock, as you're in for some headaches.

Comment: on windows with cygwin, you need both of the above flags to get pip to ignore caches.  it's a weird design - one would think that adding -U and forcing a version would imply I really wanted that version, not a random one that happens to be in my cache.

Answer (score 5):

Check your local cache and remove it can be help. I hava installed pymongo==2.5.2. To install pymongo==2.4.1, I remove the cache in /tmp/pip-build-root/pymongo.Then I install pymongo 2.4.1 successfully.