# Installing specific version of django

Tags: django

I am trying to install django 1.4.3 using pip.  I am running

```
$ sudo pip unistall django
$ sudo pip install django==1.4.3
```

and I get the following messagin during installation

```
 Requested django==1.4.3, but installing version 1.5.1
```

I can give more code if needed.   Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690533/pip-install-how-to-force-a-specific-package-version?rq=1

Comment: I cannon find a .pip folder or tmp folder, where might these be?

Comment: I found the build dir in /tmp/pip-build-root/Django, removed it and re ran sudo pip install django==1.4.3, same thing happened

Comment: Solved!, needed to remove the entire Django dir

Comment: @user2136807 Yeah, you have to do this because pip if finds the folder it considers the existing folder up for "reinstallation" instead of a new installation. I believe this is in the docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem while install Twisted.
requiring 10.0.0 but install 13.0.0,
finally I get the  10.0.0 package and download src, mannually installed it.
just change https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/**13.0.0** to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/**10.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a `requirements.txt` file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then, change the django version inside your *requirements.txt*
file manually:

```
Django==1.4.3
```

and finally run the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You should have your required Django version.

Cheers!