# Installing Older Version of Django

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to install django version 1.3.3 using `pip`. I have version 1.5.1, so I uninstalled it and ran this command

```
sudo pip install django==1.3.3
```

When I run it, I get this response

```
$ sudo pip install django==1.3.3
Downloading/unpacking django==1.3.3
Running setup.py egg_info for package django

warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Requested django==1.3.3, but installing version 1.5.1
Installing collected packages: django
Running setup.py install for django

warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

Its a little upsetting that it tells me, it knows I want 1.3.3.... but its going install 1.5 for me anyway. How can I tell it I really want 1.3.3?

Comment: you probably already have 1.5 installed from before. I would recommend   using a virtualenv. if not, remove all available installations of django and install again

Comment: I did have 1.5 installed, so I ran `pip uninstall django`

Comment: Try removing it manually, may be the uninstall was unsuccessful

Comment: First clean your cache as it says

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690533/pip-install-how-to-force-a-specific-package-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clean your cache for anything that looks Django-like in:

```
~/.pip 
~/tmp
```

or place a 'clean' place to install it to using the `--download-cache` option

for different versions use a `virtualenv` to install. as `sudo pip install` installs it globally

What version of pip are you using? This [should have been fixed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/709) in pip >=1.4 (the newest one currently). It might help you in the future to reinstall pip/build from source depending on where you're getting your packages from.

I know currently on Debian with my config I can only install:

```
python-pip |      1.1-3 | http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Sources
```

which as you can see does not include `1.4`.

the relevant command to generate the version #'s is `apt-cache madison <package>`, yup `madison` is actually the name of the parameter.

By the way on my version (1.3) pip install -i is:

```
  -i URL, --index-url=URL, --pypi-url=URL
                        Base URL of Python Package Index (default
                        http://pypi.python.org/simple/)
```

which is not `ignore`, though there is

```
  -I, --ignore-installed
                        Ignore the installed packages (reinstalling instead)
```

but in your case that would probably muddle things up because of django's global install

Relevant:
[pip install: How to force a specific package version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690533/pip-install-how-to-force-a-specific-package-version)

Comment: I had read that I needed to clear old builds, but couldn't find them. Just for kicks I checked one more time, and there they were in the /tmp directory. Thanks.