# warning in django installation via pip

Tags: django, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv, pip, vagrant

When I try to install django I keep getting this warning. I tried the solution mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690533/pip-install-how-to-force-a-specific-package-version) but still its the same what should I do ?

My virtual os is ubuntu in vagrant.

```
  Downloading/unpacking django==1.5.1
  Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0Mb): 8.0Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: django
  Running setup.py install for django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    changing mode of /home/vagrant/blog-venv/bin/django-admin.py to 777
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These warnings are not a problem; Django is still being successfully installed. (The previous question you mention is asking something quite different, and is not concerned with the warnings.)

Comment: thanks for your time. But can you explain why I'm getting this warning.

Comment: The warning is due to infidelities into Django's packaging files; I believe it's telling the packaging system to look for certain files which don't exist. (Probably just to exclude them in this case, as `*.pyc`, `*.pyo` files are both compiled python / compile object files which will be rebuilt in the correct location once the package is installed; `__pycache__` directories are apparently something to do with [shared package installation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/).)