# How to install a lower version of Django using pip in a virtual Environment

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to install Django 1.8 on a virtual environment in the server. using

```
pip install Django==1.8
```

But It finds the newer Django version outside the virtual Environment and installs Django 1.11 instead. Is there any way to install Django 1.8 on the virtual Environment without having to uninstall The Django 1.11 outside the Virtual Environment??

[image]

Comment: No, it does not do that. If you have activated the virtualenv it does not see packages outside (assuming you haven't specifically disabled that). Please show exactly what you did, including how you created the virtualenv, and the full output.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've attached the screenshot now. please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You haven't shown how you created the virtualenv. Did you use `--system-site-packages`? You shouldn't.

Comment: no i just ran mkvirtualenv zinvos

Comment: Can you check what version of virtualenv you have? no-site-packages has been the default since 1.7 which was released in 2011(!) but perhaps you have an even older version?

Comment: use [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), virtualenv is the thing of past now.

Comment: also it looks like you you already have django 1.11 installed in your virtal environment. run `pip uninstall Django` first inside your virtual environment. Then install 1.8

Comment: @VaibhavVishal tried uninstalling and re instaling. same result

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690533/pip-install-how-to-force-a-specific-package-version

Comment: try this `pip install Django==1.8 --ignore-cached`

Comment: @YashKumarAtri thanks, now django 1.8 is successfully installed. but pip freeze command still shows django 1.11. why is that?

Comment: import django and check its version in python terminal, by doing `django.__version__`

Comment: its showing 1.11

Comment: Just for being sure run these commands `sudo python -m pip uninstall Django` `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall Django` `python -m pip uninstall Django` `python3 -m pip uninstall Django` and then activate your virtual environment and uninstall from their too then install it again using my earlier way.

Comment: try `django.__file__` to find its location in terminal, If you find anythng remove it

Comment: actually i'm doing this on server. i've different django versions running without any issues in local. I can't sudo or remove django 1.11 from server

Comment: then find the local path of django and delete it

Comment: some other applications are using Django 1.11 so deleting is not possible

Comment: Activate your python virtual and provide me the `django.__file__`, Lets see what we can do